# C++ Constructor or Destructor? (Reverse Engineering)

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering, ghidra

I am new to Ghidra and reverse engineering, but i do have C++ experience.

I was analysing this function:

```
void __fastcall Class_J::FUN_Class_J_0044c960(Class_J *this)

{
  this->vTable = (undefined *)&PTR__purecall_004b0f38;
  if (this->pointer_field9_0x24 != (undefined *)0x0) {
    operator_delete(this->pointer_field9_0x24);
    this->pointer_field9_0x24 = (undefined *)0x0;
  }
  FUN_Class_J_0044c990(this);
  return;
}
```

Due to the *vTable* being filled here I expected this to be an constructor of Class_J.
But the call of *operator_delete* makes me think of being an destructor.

Or does this function only make sure, that the pointer is cleared?
But what if the garbage in memory at *this->pointer_field9_0x24* points to a valid address? Then it would free an random object in memory, wouldn't it?

Am i missing something?

The function FUN_Class_J_0044c990 could also theoretical be either.

```
void __thiscall Class_J::FUN_Class_J_0044c990(Class_J *this)

{
  this->field10_0x28 = -1;
  this->field1_0x4 = 0;
  this->field2_0x8 = 0;
  this->field3_0xc = 0;
  this->field5_0x14 = 0;
  this->field4_0x10 = 0;
  this->field6_0x18 = 0;
  this->field7_0x1c = 0;
  this->field8_0x20 = 0;
  this->pointer_field9_0x24 = (undefined *)0x0;
  return;
}
```

and is only called by another function:

```
void __thiscall Class_J::FUN_Class_J_0044c920(Class_J *this)

{
  this->vTable = (undefined *)&PTR__purecall_004b0f38;
  FUN_Class_J_0044c990(this);
  return;
}
```

which I would identify as an constructor.

Comment: It's possible that this is a destructor, but there's nothing conclusive that would prove that.

Comment: I would suspect that this is a constructor that contains a call to a `clear()` method that got inlined.

Comment: I can't tell for sure, but setting vtable in destructor can make sense in unoptimised build. If you were to call a virtual function from destructor, it will call the version defined by the class being destructed and not from any derived classes (which are gone by this point).

Comment: *"Due to the vTable being filled here"* also done in destructor normally to devirtual call, no?

Comment: Could you construct a class of your own, compile it and then analyze it the same way to see what Ghidra spits out?

Comment: The can even be 2 implementations for the same constructor/destructor, called in different contexts - depending on the available data. Although calling `delete` in constructor is a bit unconventional, zeroing all fields in destructor is unusual too(guarding against use after free?!).

Comment: @MooingDuck you are right, i didn't think of that. It could be the case

Comment: @TedLyngmo No, because i don't know what compiler was used and what flags were used. If i use an different compiler, the result might be different...

Comment: Sure, but you could try different setups until you get close. It's most probably, gcc, clang or MSVC and all of those are free to use.

Comment: If an exception is thrown in a constructor, destructors of already constructed bases or members (e.g. in the initialiser list of the constructor) can be called.

Comment: It is a destructor.   A destructor MUST ensure that it does not call virtual functions from a derived class (which has always already called its destructor), hence the change of vtable.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy that is a good point, I didn't think of that!